# Obtaining the distance between two entries in a vectors R

Tags: r, vector

I'm having trouble calculating all the distances between two entries in a vector. Let say i have a vector of the next form `k<-c(1,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,5,4,3,7)` then i want to calculate the distance between entries of the first five to the first seven ignoring the consecutive repeated fives and then calculate the distance between the next five and seven.
i had this idea where i made that vector k into this another vector `c(1,1,1,5,1,1,1,7,5,1,1,7)` but i´m having trouble calculating those distances between number five and seven. so this would mean the distance between the first five and 7 is 4 then for the next 5 to 7 we have a distance of 3.

Any insight would be helpful :)

Comment: I do not understand your description. Can you please show the expected result for your example?

Comment: sorry for not being a lot more explicit. well i´m trying two calculate the distance between the index of the fives and the sevens. The first five has and index of 4 and the fisrt seven an index of 8 then 8-4=4, and for the next five to the next seven we have a diiference of 3. I want to obatain those differences and save them in another vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to look at the relative positions for each five to the next seven and then choose the one with the minimum positive distance.

```
k <- c(1,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,5,4,3,7)

# position of 5s
ind5 <- which(k == 5)

# position of 7s
ind7 <- which(k == 7)

# respective positions of 5s to all 7s
dis <- sapply(ind7, function(x){
  x - ind5
})

# choose smallest positive distance
apply(dis, 1, function(x){
  # exclude negative distances
  tmp1 <- x[x > 0]

  # return value with minimum distance
  min(tmp1)
})

# [1] 4 3 2 3
```

Comment: this a great solution to my problem. I´m really thankful.This solution is reaaly good more for the type of vectors that i generated.

Comment: @Zaros happy to help, if this or other answers on SE have solved some of your problems you can accept the best answer by clicking on the checkmark.